# facing an issue while getting the output of a DOM view

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, angular

```
public total = []
  public topScore: number
  public studentStatus



 public studentData: any[] = [
  {
  "name": "rajiv",
  "marks": {
    "Maths": 18,
    "English": 21,
    "Science": 45
  },
  "rollNumber": "KV2017-5A2"
  },
  {
  "name": "abhishek",
  "marks": {
    "Maths": 43,
    "English": 30,
    "Science": 37
  },
  "rollNumber": "KV2017-5A1"
  },
  {
  "name": "zoya",
  "marks": {
    "Maths": 42,
    "English": 31,
    "Science": 50
  },
  "rollNumber": "KV2017-5A3"
}];
```

this is my console output for total array

**(3) [110, 84, 123]**

```
totalScore(){
  this.studentData.forEach(a => {
    let res = a.marks.English + a.marks.Maths + a.marks.Science
    this.total.push(res)
    console.log(this.total)
  });
}
```

this is my console output for subject wise marks array of a student and status if any subject < 20 "fail" else "pass"

```
**details.component.ts:68 (3) [43, 30, 37]
details.component.ts:72 Pass
details.component.ts:68 (3) [18, 21, 45]
details.component.ts:72 Fail
details.component.ts:68 (3) [42, 31, 50]
details.component.ts:72 Pass**

status(){

  this.studentData.forEach(a => {
    let sample = a.marks
    let values = [];

    for (var key in sample) {
      values.push(sample[key]);
    };
    console.log(values);

    this.studentStatus = values.find(b => b < 20) ? "Fail" : "Pass" console.log(this.studentStatus) 
  }) 
}
```

this is my console output for topScore value
**details.component.ts:79 123**

```
topper(){
  this.topScore=Math.max(...this.total) console.log(this.topScore) 
}
```

Here all the console outputs are showing correct but in the DOM View all the  turns **green color** and all the **status value is showing "pass"**. How to rectify this

Comment: <tr *ngFor="let data of studentData" [ngClass]="{'green':topScore,'red': data.marks.Maths < 20}">            
            <td>{{data.name | titlecase }}</td>
            <td>{{data.rollNumber}}</td>
            <td>{{data.marks.Maths+data.marks.English+data.marks.Science}}</td>
            <td *ngIf="studentStatus">{{studentStatus}}</td>
          </tr>

Comment: Don't post code in comments. Edit the post and add the code there.

Answer (score 0):

When you inspect the DOM, do you see both?

```
<tr class="green">...</tr>
<tr class="green red">...</tr>
```

You aren't saying who has the top score, only that there is one. You need to distinguish which student has top score. Also, if you see both red and green in the class, it may have to do with how you have you css styles set up and which one will take precedence depending on if you have the .green class or the .red class listed first, that is if they both have the same css selector depth.

So. Either add a property on the student having topScore = true or false, or have another class that states what the top score is and who it is that has earned top score. From here, you can do something like

```
<tr *ngFor="let data of studentData" [ngClass]="{'green':topScore.name === data.name ,'red': data.marks.Maths < 20}">
```